# VNC on Centos virtual machine

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, vnc, vnc-server

I am trying to get VNC working on a Centos 6.4 virtual machine. I followed the directions at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server. When I connect from the client, I don't get any errors, but I do not get any window displayed. The log on the server has nothing interesting:

```
19/10/2013 07:14:27 PM [IPv6] Got connection from client ::ffff:10.250.151.75
19/10/2013 07:14:27 PM   other clients:
19/10/2013 07:14:27 PM Client Protocol Version 3.7
19/10/2013 07:14:27 PM Advertising security type 2
19/10/2013 07:14:28 PM Client returned security type 2
```

On a physical host (i.e. not a VM) following the instructions from the above site works perfectly. But I've had the same problem on 3 different VMs. My xstartup file is identical on the VM and the physical host.

Is there some trick to getting VNC to work on a VM?

Comment: The guest OS most likely needs the vncserver attached. What is the output from virsh vncdisplay (guest instance/domain name)

Comment: error: Failed to reconnect to the hypervisor
error: no valid connection
error: internal error Unable to locate libvirtd daemon in /usr/sbin (to override, set $LIBVIRTD_PATH to the name of the libvirtd binary)

Answer (score 0):

This my step to setup vnc on centOS 6.4:

```
yum install tigervnc-server
yum groupinstall Desktop

vim /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
```

Add content:

```
VNCSERVERS="1:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

Set vnc passwor:

```
vncpasswd
```

Set boot start:

```
/sbin/service   vncserver start
/sbin/service   vncserver stop
/sbin/chkconfig vncserver on
/sbin/service   vncserver start
```